# Multiprocessing Pool for Object Class with multiple arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Multiprocessing to parallelize a for-loop on an object class with multiple arguments. I would like to know why the following produces this:

- sometimes it works but prints an empty list []
- sometimes it gives the following errors:

> Process SpawnPoolWorker-4: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\process.py",
> line 297, in _bootstrap File
> "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\process.py",
> line 99, in run File
> "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\pool.py",
> line 110, in worker File
> "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\queues.py",
> line 354, in get AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'func' on <module
> '**main**' (built-in)>

Below is my code:

````
class parentobject(object):
     def __init__(self, n):
         self.lst = []
         self.n = n
         for i in range(self.n):
             self.lst.append(metricobject())
         self.some_array_1 = np.zeros((self.n,1), dtype='int64')

class metricobject(object):
     def __init__(self):
          self.lst2 = []
          self.xdict = dict(a=0, b=0, c=0)

def func(n, vector):
    a = vector[0]
    b = vector[1]
    ParentObject = vector[2]
    MetricObject = metricobject()
    #ParentObject.some_array_1[i, 0] = i+1
    MetricObject.lst2.append(a)
    MetricObject.xdict['a'] = b
    ParentObject.lst[n] = MetricObject
     

# Right now:
n = 5
a = 12
b = 25
ParentObject = parentobject(n)

for i in range(n):
    
    ParentObject.lst[i] = func(n, [a,b])

# My attempt:
ParentObject2 = parentobject(n)
n_vector = np.arange(0,5)
second_arg = [12, 25, ParentObject2]


arg_passin = zip(n_vector, repeat(second_arg))

pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

pool.starmap(func, arg_passin)```
````

Comment: Some comments (for now): This is *not* a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); I cannot copy , paste and run this as is because it is missing necessary import statements. Also, your non-multiprocessing version will not run. In function `func` you have `ParentObject = vector[2]` but you are passing to it a list of length 2 so this will throw a **IndexError: list index out of range** exception. Finally, when you post a question tagged with `multiprocessing`, you should also tag the question with the platform, such as `linux` or `windows`.

Comment: Clearly, the `func` function must be *different* for the multiprocessing and non-multiprocessing versions. So you should have the non-multiprocessing version invocation of `func` commented out or, better yet, include a separate function, 'non_multirpocessing_func` that it invokes so that we know what the multiprocessing version is supposed to do.

Comment: Also, for your original, non-multiprocessing invocation in your loop `for i in range(n):` you have a call to `func(n, [a,b])` where none of `n`, `a` nor `b` vary. You just want the same values  assigned to every element of `ParentObject.lst`? If that's really the case, then you *could* use the *same* `func` for both non-multiprocessing and multiprocessing, but then your multiprocessing invocation would look quite different than what you have. So none of this is making sense *to me*. Perhaps it does to somebody else.